# Adding VM flag to pom.xml file in JavaFX Maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, pom.xml

I am trying to run my JavaFX application via Maven.

I use Archlinux + Wayland + Java 11 (JDK + JFX).

I have been getting this error message:

```
(java:26713): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 11:35:39.602: gdk_x11_display_set_window_scale: assertion 'GDK_IS_X11_DISPLAY (display)' failed
```

I should use `-Djdk.gtk.version=2` VM flag according to this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/issues/2279#issuecomment-469010726

How can I add that VM flag to my `pom.xml` file?

I've already tried to insert this code, but the syntax must be wrong.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Djdk.gtk.version=2</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

From [maven pass-compiler-arguments](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) documentation you are passing the vm argument `jdk.gtk.version=2` to the `javac` compiler, while instead from your request you should pass it to your java VM. From [maven configure](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html) documentation to handle this issue you can configure Apache Maven in multiple ways, for example using `MAVEN_OPTS` and add there your VM settings, you can check the link for additional ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Now it runs with that VM flag, but I still get the same error message. When I am trying to set up the whole same project, but with version 16 (JDK + JFX) it works.

Comment: @JohnDoe You are welcome, if it runs with version 16 but not with 11 sounds an issue  related to a not total compatibility between src code of the project and java 11 but I cannot help you with this.

Comment: It doesn't have any complex src code, just the automated generated template from Maven. I see, thanks anyway.